# can ajax call other ajax page?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I have index page,which contain div section.i want to call different pages into this div section on the basis of her-link click,this is done. when calling pages that may also using ajax call,in this case ajax call not work for this page.please tell me it is possible to call ajax inside an ajax.if yes then please help me.

**Update Edit:**

I have created a gist where i have include all used pages,script https://gist.github.com/2786811.page service_status called the view.jsp using ajax call every 5 second,on hand view.jsp interact with database and prepare view.when we do ajax call from index.jsp, service_status called but it doesn't called view.jsp file.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible but you may encounter problems depending on the way you do it. Please put a page demonstrating your problem in jsfiddle or elsewhere.

Comment: please look on gist https://gist.github.com/2786811.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make ajax call on page load using **$(document).ready(function () {...});** in target page you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to dump a `<script>` tag with `innerHTML`, it won't work.

However, you could (as an example) return a JSON object with two properties:

```
{
    html: "All your <b>HTML</b> here",
    js: "alert('JavaScript to be run');"
}
```

Then, use the `html` property to put content on the page, and then `eval` the `js` property.

This isn't the best solution, since it uses the evil `eval`, but unless you want to rewrite your whole basic structure to use callbacks properly then it's probably your best bet.